# Is there a word analogous to "dual" for three or more options?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say you have a sentence like

*The circulatory system plays a dual role of carrying oxygen to the body's tissues and removing carbon dioxide to be expelled from the lungs.*

However, what about

*The circulatory system plays a _________ role of carrying oxygen to the body's tissues, removing carbon dioxide to be expelled from the lungs, carrying cellular waste products to the liver and kidneys for detoxification, and fighting disease through the production of antibodies.*

Comment: What's wrong with "triple role"?

Comment: If you want to keep the 'al', the next step up is **triunal**: http://www.quodlibet.net/trinity.shtml It's rather obscure, but there's also **quartal** and **quintal**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartal_and_quintal_harmony You'll lose people if you go much higher, so probably better to stick with two fold, three fold, four fold....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Triple](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triple):

> Adj. having or involving three units or members - *triple bypass heart
>   surgery*

[Quadruple](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadruple):

> Adj. having four units or members

And *quintuple*, *sextuple*, *septuple*, *octuple*.  One could continue with *nonuple* but that's getting kind of silly.

(Citations from merriam-webster.com.)

Comment: Hooray! At last, somebody posts the actual answer, instead of random words that are somewhere between fanciful, high-falutin and wrong.

Comment: triple does not come after dual. comes after double.

Answer (score 13):

You can use "threefold", "fourfold", and if allowing for even more options or composed by any more parts, I'd suggest "multiple" or "manifold".

Comment: I would say "multiple" for anything above two.  You could number the portions if that makes for easier reading.

Comment: +1 for _multiple_. Personally I would go with _triple_ for three, but switch to _multiple_ for anything above that, to avoid scientific-sounding names such as _quadruple_.

Comment: What's wrong with the simple "triple"? You wouldn't say "a twofold role", so why would you say "a threefold role"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby There's nothing wrong with "triple". It's just that there the OP's sentence presents the circulatory system as having four roles, not three, and "quadruple" would certainly sound terrible there, wouldn't it? I think "multiple" is a good choice that avoids using strange adjectives once a certain number has been exceeded.

Comment: "Quadruple" sounds just fine to me.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no way of directly continuing the etymological pattern that formed **'dual'** in English. [Dual is derived from the latin dualis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dual).

The equivalent number for for three in latin would be tres or tria. In English, we have the word **'trial'**. We also have the prefix [tri-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=tri), but that is not a word in and of itself.

In suspecting that trial would probably be the closest analog, I did come across **'paucal'**, which is listed as meaning:

> **paucal**
>
> **Adjective**
>
> …
>
> 2. (grammar) pertaining to a language form referring to a few of something (three to around ten), as a small group of people; [singular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/singular), [dual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dual), [trial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trial) and [plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plural).
>
> ---
>
> **Noun**
>
> …
>
> 3.(uncountable)(grammar) a language form referring to a few of something (three to around ten), as a small group of people; contrast [singular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/singular), [dual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dual), [trial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trial) and [plural](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plural).
>
> ---
>
> Excerpts from the Wikitionary entry of [Paucal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paucal), licensed under the [CC-SA-3.0 License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

It should be noted that **I am not recommending 'paucal' as an alternative**. It is a technical word with a restricted purpose that does not really match the desired definition, especially since it is less specific.

The reason I included the Wiktionary definitions of 'paucal', despite not recommending it, is that it suggests 'trial' *would be* the word to continue the pattern but again, if it were not for a couple of problems:

The linguistic word I found on Wiktionary suggests that a similar definition exists for trial, but that definition does not match either. I think this is actually more clearly demonstrated by the closest definition in the [Randomhouse Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010](http://www.tfd.com/trial) definition of trial:

> adj. 1. of or belonging to a grammatical category of number, as in some Papuan and Austronesian languages, used to indicate that a word denotes three persons or things.

More importantly, as I am sure you are all already well aware, 'trial' usually means something closer to "test" in English, and perhaps most especially the sort of test that requires adjudication in a court of law. I expect the word to be such a popularly and traditionally pervasive word that it is hard for me to endorse using the word to mean anything else, except perhaps by way of metaphor or metonymy.

As far as I can reliably discern, ['trial' does not even derive from tria, but the anglo-french triet](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=trial) which means something closer to [try, as in an effort or attempt.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=try&allowed_in_frame=0) Thus if you want a word which is in the same series as 'dual' that conveys the meaning you desire, *I am currently of the opinion that a such word does not exist.*

You may want to consider 'plural' as a possible alternative, but it is not as specific:

> plural, adjective [Latin pluralis, from plus, pluris, more.]
>
> 1. Containing more than one; consisting of two or more, or designating two or more; as a plural word.
>
> ---
>
> [The American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster](http://edl.byu.edu/webster/term/2395040)

Comment: I do appreciate the effort, but paucal is listed as a noun and is too rare to know if it also works as an adjective.

Comment: @StuW Wikitionary lists the same definition as an adjective. However the point of this answer is not so much to suggest Paucal, as it is to corraborate the notion that the most likely word to be a part of the series does not exist. Saying no such word exists, is, as a matter of policy, [a valid answer to a single word request](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4351/124936) and seems to apply to the titular question. I'll edit the answer momentarily.

Comment: Fair enough +1 for it

Comment: The Oxford dictionary gives a different definition of paucal as a technical term invented in the 1930s, used in describing the syntax of a language: "Designating a number or inflected form denoting more than two entities but fewer than the number denoted by the plural." (from Latin *paucus*, few). This seems irrelevant to the OP's question.

Comment: Just to clarify, paucal is used in grammatical descriptions and is a part of the number system and may have exponence in the morphology or syntax of nouns, pronouns, and verbs. A singular pronoun in English is something like 'I', or 'she' whereas plural would be 'we' or 'they'. English only has singular and plural. Some languages have singular, dual and plural, wherein dual is 'we two', etc. Paucal is a category that some languages have which is more than dual/trial but not as many as plural.

Comment: Why are your Random House and American Dictionary links so wacky??

Comment: The Random House link goes to "The Free Dictionary", and the American Dictionary link goes to https://1828.mshaffer.com/, which appears to be some sort of religious dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks [That's just being pursuant to the attribution guidelines for The Free Dictionary provided by Andrew Leach.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/is-tfd-a-rtfm-online-source/6743#6743) The Free Dictionary does not usually have its own definitions but licenses them from other known sources. My interpretation of policy is that citing the original sources is required, but citing the mere host is merely optional. As for the mshaffer link, it was just the homepage link instead of a link to the specific word. I've changed it to another website with the same definition.

Comment: Wiktionary is not a particularly good source for definitions. As anaology to dual and plural, when used as a noun, paucal is a noun for the noun forms exhibiting paucal number, _not for a language that has that feature_. YOu don't say 'Russian is a paucal' (yuck). You _can_ say 'Russian has a paucal' but that is not preferred in English, rather 'Russian has a paucal number' is preferred.

Comment: Also note that 'trial' is the word for 'grammatical number of three'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Trial). Some languages do have it, but only for some pronouns, none have it for general nouns.

Comment: wave, particle, string triality. mind, body, soul trialism

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with *multiple* or *multiplex* is that they don't exclude duality.

A word that does exclude two-ness from a sense of (moderate) multiplicity is *several* or *severalty*.

However, you couldn't say something performed "a several role", you'd have to say "several roles". Or, at the risk of contrivance, "a severalty of roles..."

Answer (score 2):

The word *triune* means three-in-one.  It is most notably used in reference to the Holy Trinity, as

> the triune Deity

referring to the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit.

However, it's use can be generalized to mean the same thing as dual, but for three.

Comment: Not sure why one would use this rather obscure word when the natural and obvious "triple" is, well, natural and obvious. If somebody wrote "triune" where "triple" could be used, I'd start looking at dictionaries, trying to  figure out if they had some more nuance or more complex meaning in mind.

Comment: One definite problem with "triune" (besides the fact that spell checkers don't like it) is that it is very strongly associated with Christianity and "The Trinity".  Very likely many readers would not understand that it could be used in a generic context.

Answer (score 2):

trichotomic. : belonging to, characterized by, or based upon a trichotomy

trichotomous : divided or dividing into three parts or into threes

tri·chot·o·my : a division into three categories.

Sources respectively: Merriam Webster, Merriam Webster, Google

Comment: It would improve the answer if you included the source of your definition.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only had three roles and no more, perhaps the adjective `triadic` from `triad` would work.

Answer (score 1):

The circulatory system plays a **three-way** role of carrying oxygen to the body's tissues...

This would be the most well-known way to phrase to sentence, it's very colloquial and not so scientific but nearly everyone will understand what you mean.

Comment: This doesn't feel right, to me. And isn't a "three-way role" actually three separate roles?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, specifically for 3, and came across *trinal*. (For example, the aeroplane had dual controls.)

Re above suggestions: triple and three-fold have the connotation of identical instances or a multiplication of a single instance, which dual does not. (They also have the limitation of being related to double and twofold.) Three-way has connotations of some sort of physical object or direction, that I don't want either. Triadic might work but it is of Greek origin, whereas dual and trinal are from Latin.

Paucal, is not specific to three, but is a good alternative to multiple.